# extracting inner text of Div ID to excel

Tags: html, excel

hi i want to extract the the inner text from a HTML document i.e from a page source
   gg-roaring-brook-dairy-tofu-and-cheesemaking-kits

I want to extract "gg-roaring-brook-dairy-tofu-and-cheesemaking-kits" this alone from the page source

Comment: <div id="00N800000036X7t_ileinner">gg-roaring-brook-dairy-tofu-and-cheesemaking-kits

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var data = document.getElementById("00N800000036X7t_ileinner").innerText;
```